# Finding location of maximum D-statistic from KS test

Tags: r

I'm comparing two different empirical cumulative distribution functions using the KS-test, and I'd like to extract the location (in the ECDF) where the maximum of the test statistic is.

**Question:** Using R, is there a convenient way to extract that, perhaps from the ks.test function or otherwise?

Thanks for any and all comments.

Comment: Are you thinking the test statistic is a pointwise function? Seems to me that the stats.stackexchange.com moderators are shirking their responsibilities in failing to clarify the statistical confusion.

Comment: @Bonded On the contrary, this is a purely programming question with a purely programming answer. That makes it clearly off-topic on CV; whether it is considered on-topic here is a matter for this community to decide.  To help with that decision I have posted an answer that consists only of code and includes no statistical analysis or reasoning.

Comment: Admittedly, I have found that the proper location for asking R questions (stats or stackoverflow) can be rather muddied.  Whuber is correct in that my central confusion was in the coding rather than the statistics.  Thank you, Whuber, as that does answer what I was looking for.  Looking back, I was getting hung up on how to go from the max statistic to the index, or the function which.max().

Comment: Questions to SO shouldn't just ask for code; they should present an example or test case in code and lay out a plan for constructing an answer.

Comment: @Bonded Fair enough--and we certainly do try to apply that criterion when making migration decisions over at CV. In what perhaps is a somewhat generous spirit, one might take the guidance in this question (such as the idea to exploit `ks.test`) as a plan for obtaining the answer (and indeed it turned out to be a good idea). It's difficult to conceive of how one would present any kind of useful code to represent partial progress in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not appear you can extract such a location (which might not be unique, BTW) from the output of `ks.test`, but by emulating the key calculation there you can obtain the answer:

```
compare <- function(x, y) {
  n <- length(x); m <- length(y)
  w <- c(x, y)
  o <- order(w)
  z <- cumsum(ifelse(o <= n, m, -n))
  i <- which.max(abs(z))
  w[o[i]]
}
```

The calculation through `z <- ...` is from the `ks.test` source, while the last two lines (fairly clearly) find the location where the maximum deviation is attained.

As an example, let's generate two datasets and compare them:

```
set.seed(17)
x <- rnorm(30)
y <- rnorm(20, sd=2/3)
u <- compare(x,y)
```

The reported value of `u` is `0.04946235`.  To see whether this is correct, check it against the ECDFs and the output of `ks.test`:

```
e.x <- ecdf(x)
e.y <- ecdf(y)
abs(e.x(u) - e.y(u))
ks.test(x,y)$statistic
```

The output in both cases is `0.4166667`, indicating perfect agreement.  A plot of the situation will clarify what is going on:

```
plot(e.x, col="Blue", main="ECDF", xlab="Value", ylab="Probability")
plot(e.y, add=TRUE, col="Red")
lines(c(u,u), c(0,1), col="Gray")
lines(c(u,u), c(e.x(u), e.y(u)), lwd=2)
```

It shows both ECDFs and marks the location found by `compare` (namely, `u`) with a vertical line: it is supposed to indicate the place where the two graphs attain their greatest vertical separation.

[image: Figure]

Comment: I think your answer is an excellent R example, but I also think that the OP did not understand the statistical need for construction of a common (sorted) range `c(x,y)` as arguments for comparison of the two different ECDFs. I would have set the plot limits to `xlim=range(c(x,y))` to more generally handle the problem of 2 sets with ranges that don't overlap as well.

Comment: @Bonded Thank you for the good suggestions.  (I didn't worry about plot limits because the plot is purely to illustrate what is going on.  Some of the `ks.test` source code is devoted to handling the case of non-overlap, BTW.)  I cannot speak to what the OP might or might not have understood, but only hope that the code and the plot will help all readers appreciate the question.

Comment: I am quite a noobie but why does the ks.test doesn't the correction for large $n$? For large $n$ the code part form you needs to be changed to: `(sqrt((n * m) / (n+m)) ) * abs(e.x(u) - e.y(u))` (imho). If It do this, the test statistic is different from the one in given by $ks.test(x,y)$statistic$. I habe $n$ which sizes around 600k. Imho that is a large $n$. Hence, there is a discrepancy I do not understand

Comment: @kn1g First, you appear to be confusing an asymptotic approximation with the statistic.  Second, the KS test is useless for datasets that size.  Search [stats.SE] for extensive discussions of this test and Normality testing generally.

Comment: Thanks. I try to compare to return distributions. I started googling when the KS test gets useless because I didn't know that. I understand the point with my confusion of  asymptotic approximation and the statistic. Thanks for pointing this out. Also, I am still looking for a better way to compare the distributions as they are returns and therefore not i.i.d.

Comment: @kn1g It sounds like you are looking for *insight* and *characterization* rather than *formal testing.*  If that's right, consider visualization techniques.  A particularly powerful one (once you have learned to interpret it) is the *probability plot.*  That might be a good point of departure for a finer-grained analysis. Often the lack of independence problem is solved *via* differencing: look at techniques of *time series analysis* for guidance.